# React Redirect is not redirecting after form submission

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've tried several ways to get my app to redirect after form submission but nothing seems to work except for forcing it with using window.location. The goal is to have a user fill out a form and then after submitting they should be redirected to the home page at "/".

Right now I'm setting a value in state of redirect to false and changing it after my axios post in the submit handler, but it doesn't do anything. This is what my component looks like:

```
lass Add extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {      
        id: "",
        customer: "",
        destination: "",
        driver: "",
        deliveryDate: new Date(),
        redirect: false
        } 
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }


    handleChange(event){
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
        console.log(this.state)
    }

    onChange = deliveryDate => 
    this.setState({ deliveryDate })


    submitHandler = e => {

        var load = this.state
        load = JSON.stringify(load)
        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/add', load, { headers: {  "Content-Type": "application/json"  }})
        .then(() => this.setState({ redirect: true }))


    }

    render() {
        const { customer, destination, driver, deliveryDate, redirect} = this.state

        return redirect ? <Redirect to='/' /> :
```

After that is the rest is the form the user fills out to add data. The data is getting passed to the API so I know the POST method is working but I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: I have two guesses. (1) Your `submitHandler` is a handing a form's `onSubmit` and the page is reloading, thus resetting state, or (2) the axios call is returning a rejected promise and the happy path is never taken. Maybe a combination of both? Try cutting out the axios call and just set the redirect state. Also try validating the POST isn't returning any errors by adding a `catch` block. If anything, place the state update in a `finally` block so no matter what the redirect state update is called.

Comment: I tried commenting out the Axios POST, including a finally block but it continued to happen. What ended up working was adding this.setState({redirect: true}) before the axios post, so I think you were on to something with submit resetting the state there. I'm not sure how that works exactly but I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: If this is the `onSubmit` handler then it receives an event from the form. You can `prevent.default()` on the event and that should stop the page reloading.